# Getting an (d3) element's property that is in DOM, not in the HTML, with Selenium

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium, svg, d3.js

I am using selenium (java API) to automate testing of a page with a d3.js visualization. I need to find some data point in a chart (svg).
The screenshot of my Chrome console is probably be the clearest way to explain my problem:
My element has a data property (`__data__.key`) that is not in HTML.

[image: Chrome console screenshot]

In JavaScript, I can simply get the property by `<element>.__data__.key`.
But in Selenium, I wasn't able to retrieve it (e.g. by using `getProperty`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I will solve it using python but similar methods are available in javascript too.

Two scenarios available:

- `page_source`() property
- `innerHtml` attribute

Both approaches interact with DOM that is loaded later on via AJAX, provided you access it at the right time. Once you get the DOM source of the page you can implement the checks you need.

**page_source**

```
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
source = driver.page_source
print source
```

or

**innerHtml**

```
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
elem = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print source
```

Comment: I'm looking for something that is in the DOM, but not in the HTML. 
The pageSource and innerHTML, both only gives me the HTML.

Comment: e.g. if I would try to get the innerHTML of the element I selected in my screenshot, it returns nothing (because there is no html inside that element).

Comment: The solution has been tested on http://bl.ocks.org/erikvullings/raw/51cc5332439939f1f292/ the results of selenium (same for both scenarios) is http://pastebin.com/mkFEPnNY In the result page you have all the data inside the chart object

Comment: Thanks, I've successfully confirmed your example with ```getPageSource()``` works (in Java). (I couldn't get ```innerHTML``` to work, which returns an empty string. )

Unfortunately, similar code with a ```getPageSource``` on my webpage (which I can not make available) does not return any svg in it. 
I've no clue why (or why it does in your case).

Comment: well.. there could be a lot of reason for it but without enough info this problem is as a Needle in a haystack.