# How do I get HTML Element property using WebDriver for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, webdriver

I'm trying to test a d3 visualization using [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/).  d3 binds data to elements using a **data** property.  I can select the element fine but don't see how I access this property.

In the chrome console I see data object with:

```
document.querySelector('#myelement').__data__;
```

I've tried:

`var data = browser.execute("document.querySelector('#myelement').__data__")`

This returns the Web Element JSON Object.

as does:

```
var ele = browser.element('#myelement');
ele.getAttribute('__data__');
```

This question gives options for Python and Java but doesn't seem to work on nodejs.
[Getting an (d3) element's property that is in DOM, not in the HTML, with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671388/getting-an-d3-elements-property-that-is-in-dom-not-in-the-html-with-selenium)

Comment: isn't there something like `elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")` for node.js

Comment: there is, ele.getAttribute('innerHTML').  However it only retrieves html, I'm looking for the property associated with the element, which is not part of the mark up.

Comment: Which property are you looking for in specific?